# Forward/alias XMPP accounts on a domain to gmail.com

Tags: gmail, xmpp

I have an OpenBSD server, and I would like to configure a corporate/personal domain name to be Jabber / XMPP enabled, and to automatically proxy (forward/alias) messages between some set of local accounts and a given gmail.com Google Talk account.

Requirements, all must be satisfied:

- **no new accounts** at Google; has to work with an existing gmail.com Google Talk account
- **no new clients**, has to be able to use the corporate domain through existing gmail interfaces
- **no local accounts to log into**, an alias-only solution is needed

In email terms, I'm looking for a `virtusertable` (or some such) with *Sender Rewrite Scheme*.

In other words, it would sound like I need to setup some kind of an **XMPP-to-XMPP transport** / gateway on my server.  There surely must be such a thing, as there are many other kinds of Jabber transports / gateways available, between XMPP and non-XMPP networks; I see my case as similar to that.

(Google Apps does not fit, because it requires new and separate accounts.)

Comment: You install something like ejabberd, set up the appropriate DNS SRV records, and it more or less [works automatically](https://developers.google.com/talk/open_communications#service). You should either try it first, or clarify your question, or both.

Comment: I've tried giving a few more hints; basically, looking for a `.forward` w/ SRS kind of thing, in email terms.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, forwarding messages isn't supported by XMPP itself.

The only thing that's potentially useful would be a client (or even server module, if you're in control of the complete "old" server) that's listening on your "old" JID "A" and forwards/sends these messages to JID "B".

Comment: well, yeah, i'm obviously looking for a client/server on my server to perform this forwarding; but it has to do it in such a way as to allow a two-way communication

Answer (score 0):

There is the j2j (jabber to jabber) transport. It's old an maybe unmaintained, but it exists. See http://wiki.jrudevels.org/Eng:J2J:AdminGuide